# extjs 4.x sorting column bug?

Tags: sorting, extjs, grid, extjs4

I am using Ext 4.x. I have a list of records and several columns. The first column is called Project Name. I have 5 records: Apple, Grapes, Banana, Zucchini, Kiwi. If I apply a filter (say "Fruits") to the records, then only the following records are displayed: Apple, Grapes, Banana, Kiwi. If I then apply ascending sort to the Project Name column, the fruits are displayed in the following order: Apple, Banana, Grapes, Kiwi. However, if I now remove the filter, I see all the 5 records in the following order: Zucchini, Apple, Banana, Grapes, Kiwi instead of Apple, Banana, Grapes, Kiwi , Zucchini. The ascending sort should still apply to the column and indeed the ascending sort arrow icon is displayed in the column header. However, the sort is not in the ascending order (Zuchini comes first, followed by the fruits which are in ascending order). Is this a bug? I need the column to remember and adhere to the sort order and after filtering display the (new/additional) records in that sort order. Anyone any thoughts on this?

Comment: are you performing local or remote sorting and filtering?

Answer (score 1):

`clearFilter()` does not apply sorting. You can call `grid.store.sort();` if you want the store to sort properly.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/5aKdc/4/

Note:

Watch out if you use remote sorting... Remote sorting performs a call to the backend, you'll have to make sure the right properties are sent.